# Unable to decode json file in a controller

Tags: symfony

I'm a new symfony user, and I'm actually trainning myself on it.
Here is my problem:

```
echo $this->container->get('templating.helper.assets')->getUrl('bundles/tlfront/js/channels.json');
    $channels = json_decode($this->container->get('templating.helper.assets')->getUrl('bundles/tlfront/js/channels.json'));
    var_dump($channels);
```

I would like to decode a JSON file in my controller, but here is what the echo and vardump give me:

```
/Symfony/web/bundles/tlfront/js/channels.json ( the echo)
null (the var_dump)
```

It seems that the path to the file is correct but json_decode doesn't work.

`json_last_error()` returns 4 which is `JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX`

But, when I run the json string in http://jsonlint.com/ it returns Valid JSON

Any ideas or advices ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dude, it has nothing to do with Symfony... `json_decode` only accepts strings:

http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php

That's why you're getting the syntax error. Just read the file with `file_get_contents` and you're done:

```
$path = $this->container->get('templating.helper.assets')->getUrl('bundles/tlfront/js/channels.json');
$content = file_get_contents($path);
$json = json_decode($content, true);
```

BTW, Symfony comes bundled with Finder, a really nice tool to search and get all the files you need: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/finder.html